# How to evaluate Floor[1/2 + Arg[z]/(2π)] with Re[z] > 0

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I want to do a series expansion of an expression containing `Gamma` functions with specific arguments. An example is the following:

```
Series[Gamma[I p/x + z /x], {x, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {x > 0, p > 0, z > 0}]

(* (2^-Floor[1/2 + Arg[(I p)/x + z/x]/(2 π)]) ... *)
```

The result then depends on expressions containing Floor functions:

```
 Floor[1/2 + Arg[(I p)/x + z/x]/(2 π)]
```

However, because I am assuming all variables to be positive (and nonzero) the Arg[] will not return any values outside the open interval (-π/2, π/2). Therefore, the `Floor` expresisons should simplify to just 0.

Now I would like to know how I can get *Mathematica* to do this simplification automatically.

Maybe this is something that can be done by adding rules to `FullSimplify` with the option `TransformationFunctions`?

Answer (score 2):

I'll use `FullSimplify` here, even though `Simplify` can also be used and gives results that are almost as simple.

First of all, the simplification goes further if you convert the `SeriesData` output into a normal expression:

```
FullSimplify[
 Normal[Series[Gamma[I p/x + z/x], {x, 0, 0}]],
 Assumptions -> {x > 0, p > 0, z > 0}
 ]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
> \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-\frac{z+ip}{x}}\left(\frac{z+ip}{x}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z+ip}{x}} & \arg(z+ip)<\pi\\
> \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-\frac{z+ip}{x}}\left(-\frac{z+ip}{x}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z+ip}{x}}\csc\left(\frac{\pi(z+ip)}{x}\right) & \text{True}
> \end{cases}
>  $$

From this output we can see what needs to be done in order to get an even simpler result:

This seems to be one of those situations where the border case is preventing a further simplification. Although it's really impossible to get the equality `Arg[I p + z] == π` under the given assumptions, *Mathematica* needs us to say so explicitly:

```
FullSimplify[
 Normal[Series[Gamma[I p/x + z/x], {x, 0, 0}]],
 Assumptions -> {x > 0, p > 0, z > 0, Arg[I p + z] < Pi}
 ]
```

> $$\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-\frac{z+i p}{x}} \left(\frac{z+i
>    p}{x}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z+i p}{x}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The point of my question is how to somehow implement the last assumption automatically and not by hand. The reason for this is that I am working with an expression than results in a much larger output with multiple different Floor[..Arg[]] combinations. And it is a bit of a pain finding them and adding the extra assumption for all separate cases. (Maybe in the end implementing something like this will be more work than just adding the assumptions, but I am also curious if and how such an implementation would be possible)